# How do I get URL parameters from a link to form a new link in a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm pretty new to jQuery and Greasemonkey, but I want to reform a URL.

For example, given:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?value1=blabla1&sid=blabla2&mid=blabla3
```

I want:

```
link://www.example.com/blabla1/data/blabla2/blabla3.ext
```

I tried code like this:

```
var sid=document.URL.substring(document.URL.indexOf('sid=')+15); 
// How do I set the length of blabla2 ? -7 ?
```

Hopefully someone understands what I mean and can help me out a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular-expression searches to get the values.
If you know the param names in advance, it's more straightforward than it looks...

```
var searchableStr   = document.URL + '&';

var value1  = searchableStr.match (/[\?\&]value1=([^\&\#]+)[\&\#]/i) [1];
var sid     = searchableStr.match (/[\?\&]sid=([^\&\#]+)[\&\#]/i)    [1];
var mid     = searchableStr.match (/[\?\&]mid=([^\&\#]+)[\&\#]/i)    [1];
```

.
The last bit is then something like:

```
var domain  = searchableStr.match (/\/\/([w\.]*[^\/]+)/i) [1];

var newlink = '//' + domain + '/' + value1 + '/data/' + sid + '/' + mid + '.ext';  
.
```

.

PS: It's only slightly more work if you don't know the names in advance.
PPS: This is educational code.  Beware of extra spaces and malicious data, when using in the wild.

Comment: Thank you Brock.
I know the param names. Each Image on the page is linked to "index.php?param=value1&param2=.........."
I tried now but I'm not sure how to "re-write" every link on the page with these param. Other then that I think your example will work just great. :)

Comment: You didn't ask about every link, you asked about document url.  It's not good to change the question midstream.  ;-)

Anyway, for every link, you would grab them with an XPATH search or something like `document.getElementsByTagName ('a')`.

But, you should open a new question for that, and post a link to the web page in question -- or at least include a paste of the exact link-code in question.

Mark this question answered to increase the odds that the next one will be too.

Comment: Sorry about that. :P Thank you very much for the help Brock. I'll figure it out with some reading and testing. ;)